# How to debug a script causing web page to take long time to load?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

An internal web site at my company has a page that takes rather long time to load. When I view the page using IE 11, the following message is displayed:

> [domain] is not responding due to a long-running script

The message dialog has a "stop script" button but no "debug" button.

This site uses a large amount of JavaScript scripts built in the past and I would need to debug it to try to determine which one of them is causing this problem.

My problem is that IE does not allow me to launch the F12 developer tools until after the page has loaded, and if I open the F12 tools before loading the page and then reload the page, the debug tools window disappears.

**The questions I would like to ask:**

1. How can I get the F12 tools to stay open to profile the opening of
   the page?
2. Or is there a way to debug scripts running on page load using
   Firefox (v.45.8) debugging tools?

Comment: Can you stop running the script, open the profiler and then reload?

Comment: Why don't you open it up before you navigate to the page.

Comment: Firefox tools are no different than IEs....

Comment: Hi @richbai90, I had tried the sequence of stopping the script, opening the profiler and then reloading the page, and that is where the debugging window disappears (when I reload the page).

Comment: Hi @epascarello, in my question I do already mention that if I open the F12 tools before loading the page, and then reload the page, the debugging window disappears. I thought that perhaps the Firefox tools have some persistence setting in them.

Comment: Do you have control over the page? Just remove scripts until it doesn't show the message, then add back until you do. Then you've found your candidates for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep F12 developer tools open:

- To get the Internet Explorer toolbar to stay visible, click **Alt**, click **View**, point to **Toolbars** and check **Menu bar**, and then click **Lock the toolbars**. [Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589500.aspx) from Microsoft

Debug alternatives in IE:

- If you have access to files, you can stick this tag to the page you are trying to debug and it will open [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable): `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>`
- If you don't have access to files you can still use Firebug Lite with this [bookmarklet](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable): `javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');`
- Use [IEDiagnosticsAdapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/IEDiagnosticsAdapter). It is a proxy that enables tools to debug and diagnose IE using the Chrome remote debug protocol.
- Install [Debug Bar](http://www.debugbar.com/), which provides an extended feature-set to the built-in developer tools.
- Install [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which emulates various IE instances (versions), and use its built-in Debug Bar. With that approach, you can also pin-point version-specific problems.

Also you can look at [How to troubleshoot script errors in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308260/how-to-troubleshoot-script-errors-in-internet-explorer) article by Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you Emre Piskin, I was a bit surprised but the instructions to lock the toolbars actually did cause the window to stay open.